# capturing video stream using piCam

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, opencv, ubuntu, python-2.x

i'm trying to capture the video stream using piCam.
but i get this warning and the execution stops
[image]

this the code:

this the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640) 
cap.set(4,480) 
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: # press 'ESC' to quit
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is `$DISPLAY` set?

Comment: oh, no.. it returns a blank line.. well.. could you tell me please how to set it?

Comment: Do you have a GUI running? Usually, when you open a terminal window from the GUI, `$DISPLAY` is set to the correct value.